# Models get scrambled using my own .obj loader

Tags: c++, .obj

I have been working on this .obj loader for a long time (2 weeks) and I have only been working with one model, which is a model of a car. I got bored with the car so i tried a cube and it appeared as a mess of triangles. whats interesting is that the same cube displayed fine before.

```
void loadObjv2(std::string path, ScreenRatio screenRatio)
{
    std::string fileContent = LoadFile(path);

    std::vector<Vertex> vertexVec;
    std::vector<Face> facesVec;
    std::vector<TexCoord> texCoordVec;
    std::vector<Normal> normalVec;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, Point> faceMap;

    std::vector<uint32_t> indicesVec;
    std::vector<float> verticesVec;

    //parse the obj file
    // Use std::istringstream to iterate over lines
    std::istringstream iss(fileContent);
    std::string line;

    size_t verticesSize = 0;
    size_t facesSize = 0;
    size_t texCoordsSize = 0;
    size_t normalsSize = 0;

    std::vector<std::string> verticesS;
    std::vector<std::string> texCoordsS;
    std::vector<std::string> normalsS;
    std::vector<std::string> facesS;

    //qualify lines for parsing
    while (std::getline(iss, line)) {
        if (line.data()[0] == 'v' && line.data()[1] == ' ') {
            verticesSize++;
            verticesS.push_back(line);
        }
        else if (line.data()[0] == 'f' && line.data()[1] == ' ') {
            facesSize++;
            facesS.push_back(line);
        }
        else if (line.data()[0] == 'v' && line.data()[1] == 't') {
            texCoordsSize++;
            texCoordsS.push_back(line);
        }
        else if (line.data()[0] == 'v' && line.data()[1] == 'n') {
            normalsSize++;
            normalsS.push_back(line);
        }
    }

    std::thread t1 = std::thread([&verticesS, &vertexVec]() {
        for (std::string& s : verticesS)
        {
            std::vector<std::string> sv = splitString(s, ' ');
            Vertex v = {};
            for (int i = 1; i < sv.size(); i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                case 1:
                    v.x = std::stof(sv[i]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    v.y = std::stof(sv[i]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    v.z = std::stof(sv[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            vertexVec.push_back(v);
        }
        });
    std::thread t2 = std::thread([&facesS, &facesVec]() {
        for (std::string& s : facesS)
        {
            std::vector<std::string> sv = splitString(s, ' ');
            Face f = {};
            std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> ssv(3);
            for (int i = 1; i < sv.size(); i++)
            {
                switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    ssv[i - 1] = splitString(sv[i], '/');
                    for (int z = 0; z < ssv[i - 1].size(); z++)
                    {
                        switch (z)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            f.vi1 = std::stoi(ssv[i - 1][0]);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            f.ti1 = std::stoi(ssv[i - 1][1]);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            f.ni1 = std::stoi(ssv[i - 1][2]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ssv[i - 1] = splitString(sv[i], '/');
                    for (int z = 0; z < ssv[i - 1].size(); z++)
                    {
                        switch (z)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            f.vi2 = std::stoi(ssv[i - 1][0]);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            f.ti2 = std::stoi(ssv[i - 1][1]);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            f.ni2 = std::stoi(ssv[i - 1][2]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ssv[i - 1] = splitString(sv[i], '/');
                    for (int z = 0; z < ssv[i - 1].size(); z++)
                    {
                        switch (z)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            f.vi3 = std::stoi(ssv[i - 1][0]);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            f.ti3 = std::stoi(ssv[i - 1][1]);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            f.ni3 = std::stoi(ssv[i - 1][2]);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            facesVec.push_back(f);
        }
        });
    std::thread t3 = std::thread([&normalsS, &normalVec]() {
        for (std::string& s : normalsS)
        {
            std::vector<std::string> sv = splitString(s, ' ');
            Normal n = {};
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                case 1:
                    n.x = std::stof(sv[i]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    n.y = std::stof(sv[i]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    n.z = std::stof(sv[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            normalVec.push_back(n);
        }
        });
    std::thread t4 = std::thread([&texCoordsS, &texCoordVec]() {
        for (std::string& s : texCoordsS)
        {
            std::vector<std::string> sv = splitString(s, ' ');
            TexCoord t = {};
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                case 1:
                    t.x = std::stof(sv[i]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    t.y = std::stof(sv[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            texCoordVec.push_back(t);
        }
        });
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    uint32_t index = 0;
    for (const Face& f : facesVec)
    {
        std::array<Point, 3> points;
        points[0] = Point(f.vi1, f.ti1, f.ni1);
        points[1] = Point(f.vi2, f.ti2, f.ni2);
        points[2] = Point(f.vi3, f.ti3, f.ni3);

        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
        {
            if (faceMap.find(points[i].to_string()) == faceMap.end())
            {
                points[i].index = index;
                faceMap.insert(std::make_pair(points[i].to_string(), points[i]));
                index++;
            }

            auto it = faceMap.find(points[i].to_string());
            indicesRender.push_back(it->second.index);
        }
    }

    verticesRender.resize(faceMap.size() * 11);

    uint64_t count = 1;
    for (auto& f : faceMap)
    {
        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 0] = vertexVec[f.second.vi - 1].x;
        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 1] = vertexVec[f.second.vi - 1].y;
        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 2] = vertexVec[f.second.vi - 1].z;

        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 3] = 0.4f * count;
        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 4] = 0.2f * count;
        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 5] = 0.3f * count;

        if (count >= 3) count = 0;

        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 6] = texCoordVec[f.second.ti - 1].x;
        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 7] = texCoordVec[f.second.ti - 1].y;

        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 8] = normalVec[f.second.ni - 1].x;
        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 9] = normalVec[f.second.ni - 1].y;
        verticesRender[f.second.index * 11 + 10] = normalVec[f.second.ni - 1].z;

        count++;
    }
}
```

I know that the code is extremely unclean and unpotimized but this is something I'm still working on.

files:

car: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SJiDVCNNSnCJ3BF8diR5h7266r1Zf4ee/view?usp=sharing

cube: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HhCLxhTqwc2wXsDNN1leb70zI4SODX4b/view?usp=sharing

when I pass the data to render it using vulkan with no back culling it appears as a mess of triangles that fit in the shape of the model.

The car.obj renders fine but cube.obj renders as this mess.

this is a part of a class and the indicesRender and verticesRender are a part of it.